# Can't save and instantiate a child class in my django model

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

Ok now I changed my models as follow:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Company(User):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)


class Employee(User):
    pass
```

When I run from pytho manage.py shell the following commands:

```
u = Employee(first_name = 'john', last_name = 'smith', password = 'test', email = 'smith@gmail.com')
u.save()
e = Employee(user = u)
e.save()
```

I get the following errors and can't really understand why.
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't try to reinvent the wheel, you should follow djangos documentation on how to create your own user model

Comment: Couldn't find anything. Any reference?

Comment: Going to go further than Sayse. You **must not** implement user authentication on your own.

Comment: [Nothing at all?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model).... First result for "django custom user model"

Comment: Can you please give the file where creating employee object??

Comment: What following errors ?

Answer (score 0):

when writing:

```
class x(y)
```

in Python this means x extends (inherit from) y.

while

> class Employee(User):
>        pass

makes a little sense (an employee is a user), this

> class Company(User):

makes no sense at all (Company is not a user).

If you want that a user will have the right to log in as a company, I'd advise to use foreign key:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user_with_permissions_fk = models.ManyToManyField((User)
```

As to this piece of code:

> u = Employee(first_name = 'john', last_name = 'smith', password = 'test', email = 'smith@gmail.com')
>   u.save()
>   e = Employee(user = u)
>   e.save()

Please provide your syntax error -or- please consider replacing with this code:

```
new_records_to_insert = []
new_records_to_insert += Employee(first_name = 'john', last_name = 'smith', password = 'test', email = 'smith@gmail.com')
new_records_to_insert += Employee(first_name = 'john', last_name = 'smith', password = 'test', email = 'smith@gmail.com')
Employee.objects.bulk_create(new_records_to_insert)
# No need to .save()
```